# Creating a strongly typed TS dictionary from an array of objects using reduce

Tags: typescript

I have often found myself in a situation where i have an array of objects and I want to transform this into a dictionary of objects. The objects may have a known shape of some sort but they still vary from object to object. What I need is for the resultant object/dictionary to:

1. Be type-aware of the discrete properties set on the dictionary
2. Know the particulars of each database tables columns/properties

A classic use case is a database's tables. In this case, the dictionary would represent an API for each table and therefore it would maybe share some methods like `select`, `update`, etc. but the properties which it is operating on are going to vary model by model.

In this case, let's assume an interface of `ITableDefinition<T>` as the general definition of each table's API but the generic  being the specifics brought in by the underlying table. Now let's say I'm wrapping up all the tables with the following `Database()` function:

```
import { ITableDefinition } from "./Table";

type IDatabase<T extends { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } = any> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

function Database(...tables: ITableDefinition<any>[]) {

  return {
    tables: arrayToObject(tables),
    tableNames,
  };
}

// provided by @jcalz
function arrayToObject<T extends { name: S }, S extends PropertyKey>(
  /** an array of objects */
  arr: readonly T[]
) {
  return arr.reduce(
    (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v.name]: v }),
    {} as { [V in T as V["name"]]: V }
  );
}
```

The interface `ITableDefinition` in the above example is:

```
import * as t from "io-ts";

export interface ITableDefinition<T extends object> {
  name: Readonly<string>;

  is: t.Mixed["is"];
  encode: t.Mixed["encode"];
  decode: t.Mixed["decode"];

  select: (cols: keyof T) => string;
  update: (record: Partial<T>) => string;
}
```

As you can see, the `tableNames` are successfully returned as an array of strings because every table has a "name" property which is always a string. Sadly, however, `tables` is a union type instead of a discriminated union.

> Note: this much progress was only achieved with the help of @jcalz invaluable contribution of the `arrayToObject` function.

This problem is avoided when we use test cases with statically typed objects where we can use the `as const` TS keywords. This *will* bring it back to a discriminated union but in our table example this is not possible.

---

Important:

The answer and insight provided by @jcalz was essential to arrive at a solution but by itself it did not solve the full problem where with the aforementioned `Table()` function was producing the objects and henceforth why the use of TS's `as const` wasn't an option.

To benefit the community I have posted a fully working solution but most of the heavy lifting/smarts came from @jcalz. If anyone has a more graceful solution in the future I'll be happy to prefer yours over mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step we must take is to change the `ITableDefinition` interface to take a second generic type `S`:

```
export interface ITableDefinition<T extends object, S> {
  name: S;

  is: t.Mixed["is"];
  encode: t.Mixed["encode"];
  decode: t.Mixed["decode"];

  select: (cols: keyof T) => string;
  update: (record: Partial<T>) => string;
}
```

And then we must also change our signature of the Table function to:

```
export const Table = <
  T extends { name: Readonly<string> },
  S extends T["name"] = T["name"]
>(
  model: t.Type<T>
): Readonly<ITableDefinition<T, S>> => {
  return {
    // basics
    name: model.name as S,
    // io-ts
    is: model.is,
    encode: model.encode,
    decode: model.decode,
    // CRUD
    select: (cols) => `this is just a test`,
    update: (record) => `this is just a test`,
  };
};
```

This allows us to infer `S` for each call and to Table and thereby ensure that the "name" property is a literal type and not just the generic `string` type. Already examples like the following result in a discriminated union (and thereby strong typing):

```
const tables = arrayToObject(Table(Song), Table(Playlist));
expect(result.Song.name).toBe("Song");
expect(result.Playlist.name).toBe("Playlist");
// this one shows that the select() method understands the distinct
// columns on our Song table.
expect(result.Song.select("artist")).toBe("this is just a test");
```

This is great but in our original problem we talked about a small wrapper function called `Database()`. To make this behave in its most basic form we can do this:

```
export function Database<T extends ITableDefinition<any, S>, S extends PropertyKey>(
  tbls: readonly T[]
) {
  return {
    tables: arrayToObject(tbls),
    tableNames: tbls.map((table) => table.name),
  };
}
```

> Note: the original problem had a destructured tables input to `Database` and at least at first blush it would appear this destructuring throws TS off enough that the dark arts we're using no longer work. From my standpoint the API looks kinda cooler destructured but it's not a hill i'm willing to die on.

All code in this working answer can be found in the `answer` branch of the same repo referred to in the question. The link is below:

- [Working Example](https://github.com/ksnyde/type-strong-reducer/tree/answer)

Answer (score 3):

You'll definitely need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to convince the compiler that `reduce()` will return a value of the type you desire, since the compiler won't be able to automatically follow the concept of "copy the `name` property from each element of the array to a key".

As for which type you desire, here's one possibility:

```
function arrayToObj<
    T extends { name: S }, S extends PropertyKey
>(arr: readonly T[]) {
    return arr.reduce(
        (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v.name]: v }),
        {} as { [V in T as V["name"]]: V }
    );
}
```

We are saying that the `arr` input to `arrayToObj()` is of type `readonly T[]` for some generic type `T` that has a key-like `name` property.

In a perfect world you could just say `T extends {name: PropertyKey}` and be done with it, but unfortunately this will usually cause the compiler to infer a wide type like `string` for the `name` property when you call `arrayToObj()`.  But that won't work for you; you need actual [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) keys.  So I introduce a new type parameter `S extends PropertyKey` and use that as the `name` property.  This seemingly extraneous parameter serves to give the compiler a hint that we want literal `name`s if possible.  Yes, it's black magic.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a feature request to allow for a less arcane way to do such hinting.

Anyway, the output type is `{ [V in T as V["name"]]: V }`.  This is using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) as introduced in TypeScript 4.1 to say "for each element value `V` in the full union of element values `T` in the `arr` array, we want a *key* of type `V["name"]`.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const obj = arrayToObj([
    { name: "foo", val: 123 },
    { name: "bar", val: "bar" },
    { name: "baz", val: new Date() }
]);
/* const obj: {
    foo: {
        name: "foo";
        val: number;
    };
    bar: {
        name: "bar";
        val: string;
    };
    baz: {
        name: "baz";
        val: Date;
    };
} */

console.log(obj.foo.val.toFixed(2)); // 123.00
console.log(obj.bar.val.toUpperCase()); // BAR
console.log(obj.baz.val.getFullYear()); // 2021
```

Looks good.  The implementation and the compiler agree about the type of `obj`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwCpwPIBGAVgDwCwAUItYtogKYAeU9YAJgM6IDeiYyAW3oAuRAGVEAXwA04hs1adEABVRwADvVRRMAaXqZKAPgAUaVKNT1kbBABtMtANoBdAJQ9KNRFaghUSOYAdFZsIBD0Jl7eNGYQELIAbh4AvEaIJrxB2cjxsk6JQfxCLqKJUm7S0TE8kihcvE4AaogwSHTIXE1OAETF9D0upYgtktWIbgDclGMUlBAIHFCIcMSIKSjoWLiERCZO47z9oj3AcHA9Sch2ogCMAEwAzFJVVDRHgiKIPQRol4iJa4nX6oHovQ58T7A5AAL3+gJufHoAHdEAARZAsEweWbuaYUAD0ACpEAswEsVsRRNxxmc4NTxt5jt86T18TVqAjRGAQAICFp2TRJILqCCGW8asyfn8RTEuYglqg2gBzWXC8a-GHijmQoTQuGy7zyjEsNX4upEgmUeaLOB2ehBOxwZUmVZEIJ0oIIoJQOAAMRgjHobBM9zcU0QBIJiAejyCAAZ4zbyXaHU6XW6giCvdcfXAAKrqTSoADCnUi4cmkejACEAIIAJWTHFTjudruIWdhObsQWV9CgfpAdjsAE1rKhsRGo4h7vH7rdKEA)

Comment: this might improve things a bit but it fails to achieve what I'm aiming for in two important ways. Most importantly for my use case is that I'm able to export the object to a consumer and they will then be able to auto-complete the names of the tables but still have no type support on the dictionary so the user is not told what tables exist and can choose any string name they like. [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/g2qJSJ3r8Wn).

Comment: the second issue is that while your tests print the right results at run-time, they would need type guards to transpile in TS as the "value" property in your tests are simple union types not discriminiated unions. [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/t9AsM0Khh8).

Comment: there is a third issue as well -- which may be better left as a separate matter -- but inference which works on the original object is lost when the object leverages generics. [Screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/ZmgCKibIpL).

Comment: it is clear the force is very strong with you in TS so maybe what I'm hitting is a real limit of TS? I hope not but I can't find any ways forward here and my time budget is running out. I have updated the [repo](https://github.com/ksnyde/type-strong-reducer) with your translation function and added further tests. If you have any further ideas I remain keenly interested.

Comment: Considering we are running through a function, and that the function's run-time knows the keys I would have thought we could at least address item #1 and have the dictionaries keys be explicitly typed string values. With that in place and if I can find a different way around #3, I could live with issue #2.

Comment: If you write `const foo = { name: "foo", val: 123 }` and allow the compiler to infer the type of `foo`, it will infer `{name: string, val: number}` because it has no idea that you will later care about the string literal value of `name`.  You should instead use `const foo = {name: "foo", val: 123} as const` or the like to give a hint that you do care, and things should start working, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/nWPozm). If you have further issues in need to answers in this question, I suggest you edit your original question [mcve] (and use text, not images/videos) so I can address them.

Comment: the full text was provided in the last link to the repo (all code and all tests). As I've said before, I'm providing _more_ by providing screenshot. The power of AND.

Comment: I have validated that if all types are marked `as const` that issue #1 and #2 is sorted. I am now trying to validate that a less static example can follow this same pattern but hopeful. Issue #3 does remain.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect my currently remaining problem. The [github repo](https://github.com/ksnyde/type-strong-reducer) has all up-to-date code and tests.

Comment: If you only know a value at runtime, you probably won't get much better than `{[k: string]: SomeUnfortunateUnion}`; that's the nature of unknown strings. I'm not sure if there's another approach which would work better. As for further work here on my part, I would prefer a self-contained minimal example suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE. The "minimality" (not a word, is it) is important because it gets me to something I can work on quickly. An appropriately configured web project link is second-best but the barrier-to-entry must be low (no installing, no creating accounts, etc).

Comment: I understand, and I'm sorry my example wasn't minimal enough. Believe it or not, i created this repo for this purpose. The actual repo is private and much more complex.

Comment: So is it correct that a function receiving a string name but returning an interface can't force the `name` to a literal? Seems this should be possible but I have yet to get it to work.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to make this as the correct answer though as outside of this part it is working. I will treat the remaining part as a separate problem.

Comment: btw, i did genuinely mean it that if you have a Patreon page or equivalent I would like to contribute to you.